# Earlier or Before

Tags: word-usage, usage

I had to wake up at 6:00am but my mom woke me up at 5:45am instead (and intentionally). So what sounds better:

> She woke me 15 minutes earlier.
>
> She woke me up 15 minutes before. (six)

What sounds the best?

> My dad doesn't like being woken up even a minute earlier.

What's the best way to describe it?

Thank you:)

Comment: Both ***earlier*** and ***before*** require some contextually established time that someone *would* have awakened. The same applies to ***early***, except with that version, the "default" time is idiomatically established as *the time at which the subject **normally** awakens* (for example, the time he sets his alarm to go off). That default *could* apply with ***earlier, before*** - but it's not idiomatically established, so you should only use those if your context has explicitly identified the specific ***later*** time at which he intended to wake / be woken.

Answer (score 1):

Best in both examples would be *early*.

```
 She woke me 15 minutes early.
```

and

```
 My dad doesn't like to be awakened even a minute early.
```

Comment: So, "early" is more likely to be used in this context then?

Comment: Yes. In this context, *early* means "before the planned, intended, or agreed time."